# Pass parameter to class which inherits an interface

Tags: c#, interface, signalr

I am trying to use dependency injection in a signalr application, I am currently using this document as a guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

The problem I am having is that I have a class that inherits an interface and requires a parameter in the constructor.

```
public partial class ConnectionService : IConnectionService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Connection> _connectionRepository;

    public ConnectionService(IRepository<Connection> connection)
    {
        this._connectionRepository = connection;
    }
}
```

In the document I am using the code sample says to use this block of code:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(
        typeof(ChatHub), 
        () => new ChatHub(new ChatMessageRepository()));

    App.MapSignalR();

    // ...
}
```

The problem I am having with using this on my project is that the ConnectionService class requires a parameter IRepository

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(
        typeof(ChatHub),
        () => new ChatHub(new ConnectionService()));
```

I am new to using interfaces so I am unsure what I am meant to actually be passing, whenever I try to pass an object like IConnectionService or IRepository it says I can't use these as a type.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with code like this???  Just use the existing constructor.

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(
        typeof(ChatHub),
        () => new ChatHub(new ConnectionService(someArgument));
```

EDIT:
Your ConnectionService class may need to implement IRepository.

Comment: That's what he said he's trying to do, but the argument he's providing isn't the correct type.

Comment: ConnectionService already inherits from IConnectionService, I can't figure out a way to pass an IRepository<Conenction> parameter to use the class

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass in an instance of an interface, because interfaces can not be instantiated. The parameter you need to pass into your constructor is an object that *inherits* the IRepository interface.